# Confused with following statements in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
```

When I run the following statements...

first is not working:

```
In [1]: pd.DataFrame([[1,4],(0,1)])
...
TypeError: Expected list, got tuple
```

while second is working:

```
In [2]: pd.DataFrame([(1,0),[3,8]])
Out[2]:
   0  1
0  1  0
1  3  8
```

I am trying to make a dataframe from tuple/list inside the main list.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Also... `import python as pd`? Are you sure?

Comment: `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Hi. it was a typo sorry for that. Actually, when I run the first statement, it throws an error: "Expected list, not tuple" but when I run the second statement, it works and a dataframe is generated. Just wondering why i am having a different result in both statements. Is there any property of Dataframe that i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting finding!

Be careful with the **first** row - if it's a `tuple`, you may have a mixed rows (`lists` and `tuples`), if it's a `list` - only lists are accepted.

Demo:

```
In [134]: lst = [[0,1],[2,3],(4,5)]

In [135]: pd.DataFrame(lst)
...
TypeError: Expected list, got tuple
```

Solution - convert **first** row to `tuple`:

```
In [136]: lst[0] = tuple(lst[0])

In [137]: pd.DataFrame(lst)
Out[137]:
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```

When first row is a `tuple`:

```
In [138]: lst = [(0,1),[2,3],(4,5)]

In [139]: pd.DataFrame(lst)
Out[139]:
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```